# using setNames in ifelse statment in R

Tags: r

I noticed that if I called `setNames()` in `ifelse()` the returned object does not preserved the names from `setNames()`.

```
x <- 1:10
#no names kept
ifelse(x <5, setNames(x+1,letters[1:4]), setNames(x^3, letters[5:10]))
#names kept
setNames(ifelse(x <5, x+1,x^3), letters[1:10])
```

After looking at the code I realize that the second way is more concise but still would be interested to know why the names are not preserved when `setNames()` is called in `ifelse()`. `ifelse()` documentation warns of :

> The mode of the result may depend on the value of test (see the examples), and the class attribute (see oldClass) of the result is taken from test and may be inappropriate for the values selected from yes and no.

Is the named list being stripped related to this warning?

Comment: It looks like the `srcref` paragraph is more applicable and if, your yes or no are functions you'd use if (test) yes else no that will preserve your attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not really specific to `setNames`. `ifelse` simply doesn't preserve names for the TRUE/FALSE parameter. It would get confusing if your TRUE and FALSE values had different names so it just doesn't bother. However, according to the Value session of the help page

> A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and "class") as test

Since names are stored as attributes, names are only preserved from the the `test` parameter. Observe these simple examples

```
ifelse(TRUE, c(a=1), c(x=4))
# [1] 1
ifelse(c(g=TRUE), c(a=1), c(x=4))
# g 
# 1
```

So in your examples you need to move the names to the `test` condition

```
ifelse(setNames(x <5,letters[1:10]), x+1, x^3)
```